# Install Silverlight for Mozilla Firefox without administrative privileges

Tags: firefox, silverlight, privileges

Is there any way I can install silverlight plugin for Firefox without admin privileges? For Flash there's an .xpi extension so that I can install it on Firefox Portable.

Answer (score 5):

The installation of [Silverlight itself](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx) requires admin privileges, so even if there was an .xpi installer it wouldn't really help.

> Note that you must have sufficient administrative privileges to install Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

It [sounds like](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=578769&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a) you can't; sorry. (Though you should probably search around some more before taking my word for it.)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to extract and "install" Silverlight 3 as a plugin for FirefoxPortable v3.6.10 and SRWare Iron (Chrome variant) v6.0.475 using the techniques listed in [this conversation at PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/node/14188), and the files from the [Silverlight 3 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1ea49236-0de7-41b1-81c8-a126ff39975b&displaylang=en).

Netflix streaming and the few other tested Silverlight applications worked fine.  Netflix gave me errors (perhaps DRM issues) on my first attempt with the latest Silverlight.

To summarize the steps:

1. Download the Silverlight 3 SDK
2. Drill into the Silverlight file (with 7-Zip or similar)
3. Extract the following files to the plugin folder of your web browser

```
agcore.DLL
coreclr.DLL
microsoft.visualbasic.DLL
mscorlib.DLL
mscorrc.DLL
npctrl.DLL
NPCTRLUI.DLL
silverlight.configuration.EXE
silverlight.configurationui.DLL
sllauncher.EXE
slr.dll.managed_manifest
system.core.DLL
system.DLL
system.net.DLL
system.runtime.serialization.DLL
system.servicemodel.DLL
system.servicemodel.web.DLL
system.windows.browser.DLL
System.Windows.DLL
system.xml.DLL
```